# Remove trailing special characters with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove trailing decimal/dot from a statement. Following is the statement

```
ABC paid 10.25 RS confirmed. from bank XYZ 20125722. on 23-12-2012
```

I want to remove the trailing decimals/dot from the statement. After removed the decimal/dot, it should be like

```
ABC paid 10.25 RS confirmed from bank XYZ 20125722 on 23-12-2012
```

Please note, I don't need to remove the decimal in the `10.25`, but in other places. How can I do it with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, just use [replaceAll(String pattern,String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method on a string, like below:

```
String result = "ABC paid 10.25 RS confirmed. from bank XYZ 20125722. on 23-12-2012".replaceAll("\\.\\s+"," ") ;
```

Comment: Lets hear all the requirements then :)

Comment: Why do you replace (possibly) multiple whitespace characters with one space character?

Answer (score 0):

The regex you could use is `/\.\S+/` in Perl or Perl-regex supporting languages.  Otherwise `/\.[ ^I]/` where "^I" is TAB character.  Replace that with empty.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use is  **\\.\\s+**, because after the dot may contain many spaces or one space .

The code  following:

```
String result = "ABC paid 10.25 RS confirmed. from bank  XYZ 20125722. on 23-12-2012"
               .replaceAll("\\.\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: This would also match the decimal point in `10.25` because the decimal point is followed by zero spaces.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to match any `.` not in a number? You can use a method called [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860044/negative-look-ahead-java):

```
"\\.(?![0-9])"
```

This match any `.` NOT before a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is

```
\.(?=\s|$)
```

means match a dot when it is followed by a whitespace or the end of the string. `(?=\s|$)` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that ensures that there is a whitespace or the end of the string following, but does not match this, so no need to insert it again, just replace with the empty string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30m65)

For your java

```
String res = "ABC paid 10.25 RS confirmed. from bank XYZ 20125722. on 23-12-2012".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "");
```

Comment: You could also use `\.(?!\S)` but I guess the double negation might be confusing for some.

Comment: @Joey you are right, but I use double negation only if I have to (e.g. in a char class [^\W_] to use a predefined class, but exclude some characters from that class).